# Unable to use JQuery in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, macos

I am currently unable to use JQuery in any way in my Rails MVC - using Mac Sierra.

I have tried using the JQuery CDN, I've also downloaded the latest downloads from the JQuery website, but the problem is always the same:

Whenever I require jquery in application.js, then same error message is thrown up:

> Sprockets::FileNotFound in Welcome#index

I"ve tried various types of JQuery code in the erb file but it's always the same. There seems to be something that is preventing JQuery from working in rails and I can't figure out what it is.

I have included: `//= require jquery` in `Application.js` - I have also required every other related file that should be required. I am certain that this is not the issue I have here.

Help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: did you do `//= require jquery` in application.js

Comment: Which version of rails are you running??

Comment: Yes, I did //= require jquery in application.js

Comment: I'm using Rails 5.0.2

Comment: what is the output of `bundle show jquery-rails` ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download from the JQuery website.

Using jquery in rails just add the gem you want to use in your Gemfile located in root project. After that run "bundle install" from your terminal to install it.

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Then you can add in your Application.js the require.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Make sure your application.html.erb is calling the property files.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

If it skill doesn't work, check if your controller are using the correct layout. If your controller is setting another layout, so you need to repeat the instructions for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Put in app/assets/javascripts/application.js following and restart the application

```
//= require jquery
```

Also do in console and after restart the application

```
rake assets:clean 
rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 0):

> Sprockets::FileNotFound in Welcome#index

Add the following lines code into your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

or

```
rake assets:clean 
assets:precompile
```

Need to restarting the application(Rails server)

After this run `bundle show jquery-rails` to verify that gem was successfully installed.

Comment: Yes I have done //=require jquery in application.js.

Comment: Have you restart your rails server?

Comment: I tried the rake assets:clean and assets:precompilke in terminal, but these seemed to have no effect after restarting

Comment: Try to update gem file by `bundle update` and restart application

Comment: @Robert  if you satisfied with my answer vote up and make it correct!